# Iterate through complex JSON to find match and return associated Data

Tags: javascript, loops, filter

I've got a complex JSON that is setup something like this:

```
var data = [
{
    "source": {
            "data":[
                {"name":"A", "type":"main"}
            ]
    },
    "target": {
            "data":[
                {"name":"B", "type":"tech"}
            ]
    }
},
{
    "source": {
            "data":[
                {"name":"B", "type":"tech"}
            ]
    },
    "target": {
            "data":[
                {"name":"C", "type":"software engineer"}
            ]
    }
},
{
    "source": {
            "data":[
                {"name":"B", "type":"tech"}
            ]
    },
    "target": {
            "data":[
                {"name":"D", "type":"systems engineer"}
            ]
    }
}
]
```

basically, each entry is set up with a "source" and a "target". Each source and target has a "data" section that explains node details, plus information about connected nodes ("parent" and "children").

For my problem, I want to be able to iterate through the larger JSON, and find a name match under "target" and return all of the adjoining information as needed so something like data[i].target.data.name).

Thoughts on how to accomplish this? I think it should be as easy as a using a filter, but I'm having some trouble with that.

Check Console on this JSFiddle for full output: https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/7o3suadx/

Thank you

Comment: please add a valid data structure, for example, arrays does not have properties in literal notation. what do you mean by *source* and reference an array which is not given. where is it pointing to?

Comment: simplified question to make it a little more clear -- let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Lots of commas are missing.

Comment: In the fiddle you have hierachical data, but here everything is at the same depth. The searching methods are very different, so which do you really care about?

Comment: Which part are you specifically having difficulty with? If you don't narrow it down, it feels like a "do my homework" question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return all elements of your data whereby target.data.name equals the string in str:

```
const str = 'A';
const matches = data.filter(el => el.target.data.name === str);
```